# Notation of swapping rows on a numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, swap, numpy-ndarray, notation

Lets say we have a numpy array:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9],
          [10, 11, 12]])
```

Can anyone explain why this line is used to swap  two rows(in this occasion the 1st with the 4th)?

```
'A[[0, 3]] = A [[3, 0]]'
```

Comment: If your doubt is regarding the notation itself, `A[[3, 0]]` is accessing the 4th and 0th rows and assigning to 0th and 4th rows

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays

Comment: Are you asking why someone would use that method? Or why does it work?

Comment: I get it know. I didn't understand the way it works but know I do.

Comment: @GeorgePanailidis kindly accept my solution as answer (by clicking the checkmark next to it) if you conceptually understand it from my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the positions of two subarrays *simultaneously*.

However, doing:

```
A[0] = A[3]
A[3] = A[0]
```

would not work because the subarray `A[0]` has already been updated, so you need to do it simultaneously with:

```
A[[0, 3]] = A [[3, 0]]
A
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
```